# Is there a Software that allows me to track user progress through a mockup?

Tags: usability-testing, mockup, prototype, axure

I want to build a clickable mockup for a game tutorial, i.e. a series of screenshots the user can go through to simulate the tutorial. The path through the mockup is non-linear, e.g. at one point the user can decide which of two quests to pursue.
Building the mockup is not a problem, I've identified [Pidoco](https://pidoco.com) and [Axure](http://www.axure.com/) as possible tools for this task.
However, I want to track each users path through the mockup and I couldn't find out whether either of those or some other program has that capability.
Basically, whenever the users clicks a link between two screens, both the origin and destination screen should be written to a file (ideally a csv) so I can later analyze the sequences in which screens are clicked through.
Does anyone know of a software that has this capability built in? Ideally, the prototype should be testable on a mobile device, like in the Pidoco app.

Comment: If your mockup can be accessed via a browser as a website, you could look into [ClickTale](http://www.clicktale.com).

Comment: Use Google Analytics with your published mockup. You'll have all the analytics features of GA then.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach any tracking software to any event of a prototype created in Axure. You just have to use the AXHOOX library / extention which will allow to add any custom javascript to your prototype.

http://rootnot.github.io/axhoox/